# Corrupted (Old) name of an entity - CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, magicalrecord, xcdatamodel

I'm having the following problem: I have a model called **Chat** that needs to be updated to **Conversation** (only for mnemonic issues). The generated file still remains Chat although I've changed your name on the xcdatamodel file.

Given this I've decided to go back and: "Well, leave it as is and use Chat again", but when I'm trying to do some operation over the Chat model like:

```
Chat * chat = [Chat MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"cId" withValue:convId];
```

The app crashes saying:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'
>
> ---

I'm assuming an internal error with the entity name of the regarding NSManagedObject that makes the app crash.

I've tried deleting the Chat and Chat+CoreDataProperties files and generating the new ones with the correct name (Conversation), and I've also found that a reference to Chat name has exists into the xcdatamodel (I've opened it as source file) under the key

```
<entity name="Conversation" representedClassName="Chat" syncable="YES">
```

When I change it to Conversation the behaviour is the same again.

Any help is appreciated to solve it

Comment: Although I am a linguist specializing in ancient and artificial languages, I cannot comprehend the first two paragraphs of your question. You are using nouns and verbs out of context. Is this perhaps a machine translation?

Answer (score 0):

The MagicalRecord framework assumes that class names and entity names are the same. You can either

- Use the new entity name by changing all references to "Chat" to "Conversation", which can be accomplished with a simple global text replace.
- Abandon MagicalRecord and use your own Core Data stack. Then you can fiddle as much as you like with non-standard patterns of model, entity and class names.

In general, if you opt to use a third party framework, you will have to adapt your habits to its requirements. This particular requirement was not obvious, but from your error it is evident, that incongruent entity/class names lead to problems.